# Been sick with flu almost for a month - how deep is fall

Tags: bodybuilding, getting-in-shape

I haven't been in gym since 11 of the August because of some complicated flue/cold + tonsillitis I got.

All stuff I do I do naturally, so, basically, here is some of my excercise info was like that before illness:
 - 62.5 kg barbell bench press (3 * 10 times)
 - Chin ups (with 5kg weight in additional) (3 * 10 times)
 - 70kg deadlift (3 * 10)
 - 130kg (3 * 15) leg press

Throught my ilness sometimes I've visited friends and office, but no any hard load. Temperature most of the time was normal but it was like 37.5 last 3 days (when I get my tonsillitis, yeah)

So, what do you think guys, how long should I train to get all back? How deep is fall after such hard flu?

Comment: Can you explain "how deep is fall" in another way?

Comment: @uwnojpjm how the value of weight i used to work with would change, how fast it's possible to regenerate to work with same weightsI got before get sick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A month's rest isn't enough to undo all the work you did. Deloading by 10-20% of your previous weight moved is a common recommendation. eg. If you were pushing 60kg 3x10 then move down to 47.5-55kg depending on how you feel.

Progress linearly back up to where you were, this shouldn't take more than 4-6 weeks or so.

Comment: Well, i hope so! Tomorrow probably i will go to gym, doctor said I'm healthy now

Answer (score 2):

Typically when I get back in the gym after a long period I typically start with high volume (light weight) for 2 weeks. For example 40 kg bench press (4*15).

Followed by either

1. periodisation which Jim Stopani explains very well in this program (https://www.bodybuilding.com/fun/shortcut-to-size.html) or
2. German Volume training (40kg*10*10) (Google: German Volume Training for more info).

I'm assuming from the tags that your goal is bodybuilding (massbuilding) with little emphasis on strength. If that's the case you need to eat healthy meals and get enough rest. I know this is hard as a student but training takes a huge toll on your body and treating it well will improve your performance and reduces the chance of you getting sick.

Goodluck and happy lifting

Comment: thanks but I bet there is difference between if you just took some rest and when you been sick for whole month (lack of eating, high body temperature etc)